# I can't seem to figure out what to do next. It keeps saying "Not a statement"

Tags: java

I was given a set of code to debug and I have it all debugged except for one last line that keeps telling me that it is "Not a statement" and I am just confused about what to do next. If anyone can help me here it would be much appreciated.

[Screenshot of error message](https://i.stack.imgur.com/hQAQm.png)

Here is also the code that is in the picture.

```
// This program calculates the sale price of an
// item that is regularly priced at $59, with
// a 20 percent discount subtracted.

import java.util.Scanner;  // Needed for the Scanner class

public class Discount
{
   public void main(String[] args)
   {
      Variables to; hold the; regular price, the;
      amount of; a discount, and; the sale; price;
      double regularPrice = 59.0;
      double salePrice;
      
      // Create a Scanner object to read input
      scanner keyboard = new Scanner(System.input);
      
      // Get the regular price
      System.out.print("Enter regular price");
      regularPrice = key.next();
      
      // Calculate the amount of a 20% discount.
      discount = regularPrice * 0.20;
      
      // Calculate the sale price by subtracting
      // the discount from the regular price.
      salePrice = regularPrice - discount;
      
      // Display the results.
      system.println("Regular price: $ + regularprice");
      system.println("Discount amount: $ + discount");
      system.println("Sale price: $ + total");
   
}
}
```

Comment: I assume `Variables to; hold the; regular price, the; amount of; a discount, and; the sale; price;` is supposed to be a comment

Comment: This looks like an assignment you were given for a course you are taking? If you are struggling with the assignment you should review the course material and ask for help rather than looking for a solution on StackOverflow. There are other things wrong with the code (I can spot one other problem) and the course you are taking (if I am right) should have prepared you to tackle this assignment. Go back to the lecturer(s) if it has not.

Comment: I'm sorry, but the errors had to be inserted on purpose for you to find. Hint: the main method has the wrong signature.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Comment these two lines:

```
Variables to; hold the; regular price, the;
amount of; a discount, and; the sale; price;
```

They have to be comments.